# Do I have to terminate an empty REG_SZ value with a 0-Byte?

Tags: windows, string, registry

as far as I know strings (REG_SZ) created in the windows registry must be terminated with a 0-Byte.
But what happens if you want to create programatically a registry value with no content?

a) always terminate with 0-Byte (doesn't matter if the registry value has content or not)

b) terminate only with 0-Byte if there is a content

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must always terminate the value with a null *character*. If there is no content, then the value will be that one null character and nothing else.

Note that a character is either one or two bytes long, depending on whether you are using the ANSI or Unicode APIs.

Update: The documentation for [`RegSetValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states regarding its last parameter:

> The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in
>   bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ,
>   cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or
>   characters.

The [registry value types reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also says:

> String Values
>
> If data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ, or REG_EXPAND_SZ type, the
>   string may not have been stored with the proper terminating null
>   characters. Therefore, when reading a string from the registry, you
>   must ensure that the string is properly terminated before using it;
>   otherwise, it may overwrite a buffer. (Note that REG_MULTI_SZ strings
>   should have two terminating null characters.)
>
> When writing a string to the registry, you must specify the length of
>   the string, including the terminating null character (\0). A common
>   error is to use the strlen function to determine the length of the
>   string, but to forget that strlen returns only the number of
>   characters in the string, not including the terminating null.
>   Therefore, the length of the string should be calculated as follows:
>   strlen( string ) + 1

Now all this is not as clear as it could be, but it is well known that a null terminator in Unicode strings is actually two bytes (as is every other Unicode character in the BMP).

Comment: Is there any MSDN reference document where this is documented?

Comment: @Ferhat: I added some references, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "no content". Registry values always have content if they exist at all.

If you want a query for the value to fail, then don't create it with `REG_SZ`. Instead, just don't create it at all.

If you want a query for the value to return an empty string, then you create as `REG_SZ` with one null byte (if ANSI) or two null bytes (if UNICODE).

Answer (score 1):

While the rule is to use a) - from my experience, both a) and b) will actually work.

By using a tool like [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html), you may search for all **REG_SZ** entries with a length "from 0 bytes to 1 bytes".

When doing this, you will indeed see that **most** entries are of 1 byte length (i.e. they are empty strings, terminated with a null).

On my pc, there are 75322 "empty" **REG_SZ** entries in total, and of those, 74860 entries are 1-byte.

However, 462 of the entries are 0 byte in size, meaning they are **not** null-terminated, they are just.. ..empty, as in **completely** empty.

Most of these "0 byte" entries belongs to a few programs.

First, here are some 3rd-party programs which have actually created **REG_SZ** entries (with names), it's just that they contain nothing at all..

**ACD Systems - ACDSee Pro 5**, 169 entries:

```
    [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.***\OpenWithProgids]
    "ACDSee Pro 5.***"=""
```

**Disc Soft - Daemon Tools**, 20 entries:

```
    [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Disc Soft\DAEMON Tools Pro\FileTypesSave\.***]
    "Type"=""
```

**PSP Audioware - PSP MultiInstaller**, 105 entries:

```
    [HKCU\Software\PSP-audioware\PSP_*]
    "CurrBank"=""
    "CurrDir"=""
    "CurrPreset"=""
```

But, in Windows 7 (at least SP1), there are also a few non-null-terminated **REG_SZ** strings, however, these are the normal (Default) empty ones..

**Microsoft - Windows 7 SP1 AppEvents \ Schemes**, 67 entries:

```
    [HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.*\*\.None]
    @=""
```

And also those **.Current** which are empty, have these:

```
    [HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.*\*\.Current]
    @=""
```

All of these non-null-terminated **REG_SZ** registry settings seems to be working.. ..although it's not so easy to actually **test** this, they being empty and all.. ..but at least, there is no error messages from Windows or any of the programs when they traverse these registry entries.